# How to move an email after assigning a category to another pst file folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a boss who gets mass amount of emails and assigns them categories. I need those emails to move to a different pst file inbox named the category after they are assigned a category. I don't need to auto create inboxes.

The code I have moves an email to a folder within the default inbox folder that the category is assigned. I need it to move to another pst file inbox.

The person is using POP3. I know IMAP would be better but they are set in their ways due to old employees "accidental" deleting of emails.

```vb
Private WithEvents objInboxFolder As Outlook.Folder
Private WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

'Process inbox mails
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInboxFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInboxFolder.Items
End Sub

'Occurs when changing item
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objTargetFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = Item
 
       'Move mails based on color category
       If InStr(objMail.Categories, "Followup") > 0 Then
          Set objTargetFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Followup")
          objMail.Move objTargetFolder
       ElseIf InStr(objMail.Categories, "Business") > 0 Then
          Set objTargetFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Business")
          objMail.Move objTargetFolder
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference a folder not under the default inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446838/reference-a-folder-not-under-the-default-inbox)

Comment: `Set objTargetFolder = Session.Folders("nameofpst").Folders("Inbox)`.Folders("Followup")`

Answer (score 0):

> I need those emails to move to a different pst file inbox named just like the category after they assign it to a category.

First of all, other pst files should be added to the profile. Otherwise, you need to add them using the [AddStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addstore)/[AddStoreEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.addstoreex) methods in case of pst files stored on the disk.

If other stores are just shared folders you need to use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Inbox folder).

```
Sub ResolveName()
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Dan Wilson") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Finally, when stores are available you can use the [Stores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.stores) property of the `Namespace` class which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the `Store` objects in the current profile.

```
Sub EnumerateStores() 
 Dim colStores As Outlook.Stores
 Dim oStore As Outlook.Store 
 Dim oRoot As Outlook.Folder 
 
 On Error Resume Next 
 Set colStores = Application.Session.Stores 
 For Each oStore In colStores 
   Set oRoot = oStore.GetRootFolder 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.FolderPath) 
   Debug.Print (oRoot.Name) 
 Next 
End Sub
```